# Хранение соли пароля

Tags: c#, пароль, соль

Где её хранить и в каком виде? В базе данных, в отдельной строке в таблице Users?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96897/discussion-on-question-by-juniorone---).

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю использовать две соли.

Соль алгоритма хеширования одинаковая для всех пользователей, так что ее лучше хранить в виде константы в процедуре, которая вычисляет хеш от (логин пользователя+пароль пользователя+соль пользователя+соль алгоритма).

Соль пользователя можно хранить в таблице пользователей с полями: логин пользователя, хеш пароля пользователя, соль пользователя.

Comment: Одинаковая соль - это категорически неправильно, бесполезно и небезопасно. В нормальных системах у каждого пользователя своя собственная соль.

Comment: Наверное, это разная соль. Та соль, которая у каждого пользователя, если она хранится рядом с хешем и логином, компрометирует закодированный пароль.

Comment: Каким же образом компрометирует? Если я вам скину свой хеш пароля с солью, скажете мне пароль?

Comment: Две соли это лучше, но если злоумышленник взломает сервер, он всё равно без проблем прочитает обе соли, а своя реализация хеширования со второй солью лишь снизит переносимость и совместимость с другими системами, поэтому я считаю это немножко бесполезным

Comment: Если я получил доступ к таблице, то там еще и логин, а алгоритм хеширования скорее всего MD5 (можно другие подобрать). Осталось также подобрать порядок соединения соли, пароля и логина, и запустить перебор паролей. К тому же, не совсем понятно, почему одинаковая соль небезопасна (у нее есть конечно минусы, когда логин+пароль совпал у двух пользователей, то хеш получится одинаковый), но по крайней мере эта соль лежит отдельно от таблицы и вообще от БД где-нибудь на сервере приложений, т.е. для взлома паролей придется ломать не только БД, но и сервер.

Comment: Если вы используете логин в качестве соли, то окей, но это опять же снижает совместимость с системами, в которых, например, логина вообще не бывает. Использовать MD5 для хеширования паролей категорически ни в коем случае нельзя, потому что эта функция слишком быстрая и после получения всех солей злоумышленник вскроет большинство паролей за несколько дней. То же самое относится и ко всем SHA в общем-то.

Comment: Интересная мысль про отсутствие логина, спасибо! Правда, в такой ситуации можно вместо логина использовать соль или любой идентификатор пользователя (например, гуид). Осталось выяснить, насколько мощную и гибкую систему защиты собирается строить топикстартер :).

Comment: @andreymal то есть семейство SHA не стоить брать во внимание?

Comment: @andreymal а как на счёт bcrypt или pbkdf2? Я читал по поводу bcrypt и он мне понравился своим алгоритмом Blowfish

Comment: Их и надо использовать